# 'Windows Explorer file right click menu' in a PyQt application

Tags: python, pyqt, pywin32

I have a pyqt application that opens some data files. The files are displayed in a list. I want to add windows explorer right click context menu for the opened file.

Something like this.

[image]

I don't want to add anything in the windows explorer right click context menu.

The actions listed in menu should behave like they do in actual windows explorer right click menu.

Thanks

Comment: That is a very tall order. The only way to do it is to read the context menu registry settings and build the menu yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But If I read from registry, I have to define function for each option in context menu inside my application.

Comment: I thought when we right click a file in windows it must generate some kind of signal which spawns right click menu at that location. Can we mimic same signal from python?

Comment: You are correct that the right-dick will result in a message. But in Windows the message goes first to the window when the click happened, ..., then to the app, then to the OS. In your case, Explorer isn't anywhere in that chain. And it is an Explorer context menu you are trying to grab.

Comment: Ok I got your point. Since many applications has this feature, I thought there may be some standard library/function for this.

Comment: Well, there is, in the sense that if you call up a file-open dialogue, you are calling into the operating system (which of course shares code with Explorer) and once there the user does have context menus, and can even rename or delete files, run executables, and other things. But the menu is built by the OS from the registry and is gone when the file-open dialogue returns control to you.